# Dismissible in ListView picks up swipes from PageView

Tags: flutter

I have a list of `Dismissible` widgets inside a `ListView` on a page. The page is part of a `PageView` that I have setup with a `BottomNavigationBar` so that each page of the `PageView` corresponds to a tab in the `BottomNavigationBar`. (Basically swipeable tabs with a bottom tab bar.)

Everything works great as far as swiping between pages and tapping the tabs to change between pages. The issue is with the `ListView` on my third page.

The `Dismissibles` in my list view swipe right to delete and swipe left to edit. The problem is when I try to go back a page (by swiping right) the `Dismissibles` are so sensitive that it deletes them should your finger happen to be over them.

I have looked for ways of making them less sensitive, but since it is a "flicking" action to swipe between pages the `Dismissible` treats it as if you dragged the dismissible 100% to the right, deleting the item.

I have seen this exact scenario work fine in native apps. With native, the UI seems to know when you meant to flick away an item or if you meant to swipe between pages.

Does anyone know what I can do to get the behavior I'm looking for?